# Using regex with LIKE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

WHen i hit the follwing query I get 1 row

```
SELECT * FROM servers WHERE Node='abc_deeh32q6610007'
```

However when I hit the following query 0 rows are selected

```
SELECT * FROM servers WHERE Node LIKE '%_deeh32q6610007'
```

I am using MySQL DB.

Comment: can you pls share the table design so that i can check through fiddle

Comment: You want create table query? you can create a table named `servers` with just 1 column Node of type `var`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM servers WHERE Node LIKE '%\_deeh32q6610007'
```

Comment: Even this returned 0 rows